# TypeError: argument of type 'NoneType' is not iterable - WHY?

Tags: python, python-3.x, typeerror, nonetype

I'm trying to write a piece of code in Python 3 that takes a word and a set of letters and sees if the letters can form the given word. At line 4 I keep getting the TypeError stated in the question, and I don't know why because myLetters is a list, and it's not NoneType.

```
def formWord(myWord, myLetters):
    myLetters = list(myLetters)
    for wordLetters in myWord:
        if wordLetters in myLetters:
            myLetters = myLetters.remove(wordLetters)
            continue
        elif wordLetters not in myLetters:
            return(False)
        else:
            return(True)
```

Comment: Change `myLetters = myLetters.remove(wordLetters)` to `myLetters.remove(wordLetters)`.  Since `.remove()` returns None, you are assigning `myLetters` to `None`.

Comment: Thank you! Follow up question - the code works and returns False when the word can't be formed but it doesn't return anything when the word can be formed (it should return true). Any advice?

Comment: Remove the `else:` line, and remove some of the indentation of the `return True` so that it has the same indentation as the `for wordLetters in myWord:` line.

Comment: Great, thanks for your help!